# How can I retrieve data from a call to sqlite3.Database.all method?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

This is quite a basic question (probably a duplicate) but I am trying to make an sql query using the [javascript interface to `sqlite3`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/). The docs give examples of making queries but they only print the data to console. I want to store the data in a new variable instead and go on to (eventually) plot with d3.

Here's what I have so far. I've read somewhere that the `this` keyword may be useful here. Please assume that `db` is an open connection to an sqlite3 database and `sql` is some valid sql.

```
var data = db.all(sql, [], function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    this.data = [];
    rows.forEach((row) =>{
        this.data.push(row);
    });
});
```

Comment: just send `rows` to front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rows` holds all the data from the sql query. You must pass a function to `db.all`
that takes the parameters `(err, rows)`. This function will be called after the data is retrieved.

It sounds like you're confused about how to access the data outside the scope of the function you are passing:

```
function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    this.data = [];
    rows.forEach((row) =>{
        this.data.push(row);
    });
}
```

To do this you can define variables outside its scope to edit and assign values to.

`this.data` will not work as `this` refers to the anonymous `function(err, rows)` that you do not have access to outside of `db.all`

You can also send the info to the frontend as stated in a comment